# Wait for a value to change in python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am pinging an IP for a server with a discord bot setup. I want it to send a message whenever the output of the ping changes from 1 to 0 meaning the server has gone offline but with my current setup its just a while loop and it sends messages over and over and over forever but I only want it to send 1 message whenever **status** changes from **1** to **0**

```
@tasks.loop()
async def serverstatus():
    channel=bot.get_channel(850531139403776040)
    status=os.system("ping -c 1 "+ip)
    messagesent=0
    if status==0:
        await channel.send(f"<@&850539902675845170> Server Offline")
    else:
        await channel.send("Server Online")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
was_online = True
@tasks.loop()
async def serverstatus():
    global was_online
    channel = bot.get_channel(850531139403776040)
    is_online = os.system("ping -c 1 "+ip)
    if was_online and not(is_online):           
       await channel.send(
           f"<@&850539902675845170> Server Offline")      
    else:
        await channel.send("Server Online")
    was_online = is_online
```

If you want to exit the loop once it goes offline:

```
@tasks.loop()
async def serverstatus():
    channel=bot.get_channel(850531139403776040)
    status=os.system("ping -c 1 "+ip)
    if status:
        await channel.send("Server Online")  
    else:
        await channel.send(f"<@&850539902675845170> Server Offline")
        serverstatus.stop()
```

Comment: Both `continue` and `break` keywords are going to throw a syntax error: `'break'/'continue' outside loop`. Using `else: serverstatus.stop()` should do the trick

Comment: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'was_online' referenced before assignment`

Comment: @pachblm I've edited my answer to include a global declaration, but you might want to explicitly pass the value to the function and have the function return it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
oldstatus=None
@tasks.loop()
async def serverstatus():
    channel=bot.get_channel(850531139403776040)
    status=os.system("ping -c 1 "+ip)
    if status!=oldstatus and oldstatus!=None:
        await channel.send("Status Changed!!")
    oldstatus=status
```

I removed some code I don't know what were you doing you can add them back.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a database to store a value corresponding to the last known status of the server, for example, store

```
{
"status": 1
}
```

then each loop, fetch that value, and compare it to the newer value, and if they dont match, send the message and update the value stored